# Master_ master replication on Mariadb

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, master-master-replication

I have a nagios application running on 2 servers, i am planning to have have master-master replication for HA. for master-slave replication, slave should be read-only. in this manner is there any pre-req for master-master replication. while doing master-master replication i ran into a lot of duplicate as both the databases are auto-increment on their own and trying to replicate each other.

can some one please help to resolve the issue.

Thanks,

Comment: To avoid more troubles, don't write to both masters.

Comment: @RickJames If you're only writing to one master, doesn't that effectively make it master-slave rather than master-master? Or at least would seem to defeat the purpose of master-master replication?

Comment: I suppose a master-master setup where you're only writing to one master still has an advantage over a master-slave setup because it's easier to redefine which node is the master, i.e. you only have to modify stuff on the application side, not the MySQL side.

Comment: The purpose of M-M (vs. M-S) is ease of failover.  You already have the replication set up going the "other direction" (even though it is doing 'nothing').  M-M does _not_ provide "write scaling".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the issue with duplicate keys when using auto_increment PKs, you need to configure the system variables [auto_increment_increment](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/replication-and-binary-log-server-system-variables/#auto_increment_increment) and [auto_increment_offset](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/replication-and-binary-log-server-system-variables/#auto_increment_offset).

From the [MariaDB Knowledgebase: AUTO_INCREMENT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/auto_increment/#replication):

> To make master-master or Galera safe to use AUTO_INCREMENT one should
>   use the system variables auto_increment_increment and
>   auto_increment_offset to generate unique values for each server.

So in other words, with two masters: On master1 set `auto_increment_increment=2` and `auto_increment_offset=1`, and on master2 set `auto_increment_increment=2` and `auto_increment_offset=2`.

Comment: its worked for me. how can we check replication is working 100%?